# modeling database with 2 similar table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a database which has `product_sell` and `product_buy` tables, these two tables are different in a few fields and each one has owns comment table

```
product_sell >---< product_sell_cmt
product_buy >---< product_buy_cmt
```

now , I want to ask which modelling approach is better?

- design four tables as showed above
- design `product_sell` and `product_buy` separately with common comment table
- merge two product tables in one table with unused columns in rows or even using 1 to 1 relations

since, I will use `product_sell` and `product_buy` and their comments lonely in some cases , is it useful for indexing and performance to have 4 separated tables?

Comment: opinion #1.  I would probably go with one comment table - which means you need to share Primary Key Sequence values across the other tables - or create a link table.  This should also allow you to reply to comments with other comments without doubling up those structures as well.

Comment: opinion #2:  consider a product, and a product_transaction table where the transaction type tells you buy or sell - probably has dates and amounts.